# What is an atomic heap?

Tags: optimization, heap, priority-queue, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am trying to understand Thorup's latest priority Queue which has delete_min operation O(log log N) as presented in his [paper](http://perso.ens-lyon.fr/eric.thierry/Graphes2009/thorup.pdf).

He refers to Fredman and Williard's Atomic Heap as a part of his structure, as seen in their [paper here](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0022000005800649/1-s2.0-S0022000005800649-main.pdf?_tid=c1613b04-21ee-11e6-9341-00000aab0f26&acdnat=1464122181_281ba2fdd92151e926a082f7b45bf88b)

I couldn't find much information regarding this atomic heap and I don't quite understand how it works. Is it similar to the Fibonacci Heap? Why does it include Q-heaps inside?

Also I would want to know if it is possible to make an implementation (with today's computers) of Thorup's priority queue since I wasn't able to find an example of it.

Comment: I've had these on my list of "tricky integer data structures I've wanted to learn about for a while but haven't actually studied yet." If I get the time in the next couple of days, I'll read about them in more depth and let you know what I find. From a quick skim of the paper you linked, it seems like they're related to fusion trees and are designed to have a size that's so small that, combined with word-level parallelism, they can perform all major operations in time O(1) each, but that's all I can say for now.

Comment: ...and looking over this paper, this looks like a *highly* nontrivial data structure. Are you specifically curious about *how it works*, or *what it does?* Most future citations seem to focus on the second rather than the first.

Comment: @templatetypedef i am actually trying to implement thorup s priority queue, and he mentioned many times the atomic heap structure. I believe he does not use it in the end but i would like to know the general idea of it in order of understanding his paper better.